# How to improve this jQuery statement?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with inputs with IDs `language1`, `star1`, `language2`, `star2` etc. I need to activate the star input field if the corresponding language field has a `length > 0`.

Right now I'm using the code below, but I believe I should be able to solve this with a while loop or similar to avoid repeating the same code over and over. Can someone help me with this?

```
$('#language1').blur(function() {
    if ( $('#language1').val().length == 0){
        $('input[name=star1]',this.form).rating('readOnly',true);
    }
    else {
        $('input[name=star1]',this.form).rating('readOnly',false);
    }
});
$('#language2').blur(function() {
    if ( $('#language2').val().length == 0){
        $('input[name=star2]',this.form).rating('readOnly',true);
    }
    else {
        $('input[name=star2]',this.form).rating('readOnly',false);
    }
});
....
```

Comment: is there any function called `rating` in jQuery

Comment: Wow, at least 5 out of 11 answers that did not even replace the `if(...) y(true) else y(false)` with simply `y(...)`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#language1, #language2').blur(function() {
    $('input[name=star'+this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1)+']',this.form).rating('readOnly', $(this).val() == '');                       
});
```

Comment: Alot of nice solutions, marked this one as answer since I found it to be the most elegant one.

Answer (score 2):

Make only one handler:

```
var changeHandler = function(e) {
    $('input[name=star' + this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1) + ']').rating('readonly', this.value.length === 0);
}
```

Bind blur event with same handler for several elements using Multiple selector:

```
$('#language1, #language2').blur(changeHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

try ( not tested)

```
 $('input[id=^language]').each('blur',function(i){  
     var $this = $('input[name="star" + i +"]',this.form);        
     ($(this).val().length == 0)
                 ? $this.prop('readonly')
                 : $this.removeProp('readonly');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: You will be able to add other inputs by simply adding a class to them.

Add to all your inputs that should have the blur function a class, let's say "blurred"
And now run an "each" function on all blurred class items:

```
$('.blurred').each(function() {
   var $that = $(this);
   var name  = $that.attr('name');

   if($that.val().length == 0){
     $('input[name='+name+']',this.form).rating('readOnly',true);                       
   } else {
     $('input[name='+name+']',this.form).rating('readOnly',false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a while loop to dynamically test for any amount of items, assuming of course they are in numeric order:

```
var currentId = 1;
while ($('#language' + currentId++).length > 0) {
    $('#language' + currentId).blur(function() {
        if ( $('#language' + currentId).val().length == 0){
            $('input[name=star' + currentId + ']',this.form).rating('readOnly',true);                       
        }
        else {
            $('input[name=star' + currentId + ']',this.form).rating('readOnly',false);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) functionality of jQuery like this

```
$( '#language1, #language2, moreselectorshere' ).blur( function() {

  var trailingNumber= this.id.charAt( this.id.length-1 ),
      activate = this.value.length > 0;

  $( 'input[name=start' + trailingNumber + ']', this.form )
      .rating( 'readyOnly',  activate );

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyo

if you can, enhance your Html code for the language elements. I guess it is a input element?

You could try something like this

```
<input type="text" id="language1" starelement="true" />
<input type="text" id="language2" starelement="true" />
...
```

You could modify your jQuery like this

```
$('input[starelement=true]').blur(function() {
     //extract the 1 from the id value
     var idValue = $(this).attr('id');
     var numberValue = idValue.substring(idValue.length-1); 
     if ( $(this).val().length == 0){
       $('input[name=star' + numberValue + ']',this.form).rating('readOnly',true);                       
   }
   else {
      $('input[name=star' + numberValue + ']'.rating('readOnly',false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

don't select by using the id make another selector like class and use it as

```
$(".classname").blur(function(){
       if ( $(this).val().length == 0){
            $('input[name=star1]',this.form).rating('readOnly',true);                       
        }
        else {
            $('input[name=star1]',this.form).rating('readOnly',false);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also derive the name of the star box to be shown from the input used.
write once, use anywhere. similar to the way you would show tooltips for only a relevant input.

```
$('input').blur(
if ( $('#'+this.id).val().length > 0) {
    function(){star_id = '#'+this.id+'_star'; 
        $(star_id).show();}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a custom attribute to store the relationship:

```
<input class="language" id="language1" data-rel="star1" />
<input id="star1" />
...
```

Then use each:

```
$('.language').each(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  t.blur(function() {
    if ( t.val().length == 0){
      $('#'+t.attr('data-rel')).rating('readOnly',true);                     
    } else {
      $('#'+t.attr('data-rel')).rating('readOnly',false);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  $('#language'+i).blur(function() {
    if ( $('#language'+i).val().length == 0){
      $('input[name=star'+i+']',this.form).rating('readOnly',true);                       
}
else {
  $('input[name=star'+i+']',this.form).rating('readOnly',false);
    }
  });
}
```

Just change the i<=2 to however many times you need this repeated.

Comment: That would assume there would only ever be a set amount of languages. What if there is more? You would then need to amend the script each time...